# Merge 2 variables into 1 string and then treat that string as a variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I got this code:

```
var currentsettimevarstring = 'settimevar' + c, 
currentsettimevar = currentsettimevarstring;
```

I want the output of `currentsettimevarstring` to be `settimevar1` (or 2, 3, 4, etc)
and the output of `currentsettimevar` to be the content of the variable `settimevar1`

How can this be done?

Comment: I suppose `eval`...but that's not a good idea. Why are you doing this?

Comment: This is a reasonable thing for, say, a code obfuscation contest or to practice some sort of metaprogramming. But you should be aware that this is not a reasonable thing to do in "normal" code. There are much, much better ways to accomplish... whatever it is you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use eval for this: `var currentsettimevar = eval('sitetimevar' + c)`

Keep in mind that using eval can [be a bad idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 1):

If the `settimevar` variables are global variables, you can reference them on the `window` object using the `currentsettimevarstring` as the key:

```
var currentsettimevar = window[currentsettimevarstring];
```

If they are not global variables, then you may want to consider storing them in an array or as properties of an object that you can reference by key.

```
var settimevar = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var c = 5;
var currentsettimevar = settimevar[c - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name).

Basically, javascript has a global scope you can access with the 'window' variable, and index the defined variables like you would any other collection.

```
var c = 5;
var settimevar5 = "Some String";
var currentsettimevarstring = 'settimevar' + c, 
var currentsettimevar = window[currentsettimevarstring];
```

currentsettimevar should now be "Some String"

Comment: Only works IF they are in the global scope... or if they variables or members off of another object... which there is no indication that is the case. I don't see how this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @justnS: Because it's about the same problem, how to get the value of a variable, given the variable's name as a string.

Comment: Indeed. I did say this works for the global scope as well as any other collection.  If you were inside a function, closure, whatever, then you can use the this[] instead of window[] and achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays instead:

```
var settimevar = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
    c = 0, /* for example */
    currentsettimevar = settimevar[c];
```